# Operator in namespace scope hiding another in global scope

Tags: c++, namespaces, name-lookup

Is this a compiler-bug?

```
template <typename T>
T& operator++(T& t)
{
    return t;
}

namespace asdf {

enum Foo { };
enum Bar { };

Foo& operator++(Foo& foo);

void fun()
{
    Bar bar;
    ++bar;
}

} // end namespace asdf

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

The GCC 4.7 error message is:

```
error: no match for 'operator++' in '++bar'
note: candidate is:
note: asdf::Foo& asdf::operator++(asdf::Foo&)
note: no known conversion for argument 1 from 'asdf::Bar' to 'asdf::Foo&'
```

It compiles if you comment out the line:

```
Foo& operator++(Foo& foo);
```

Comment: [Yes it is](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2vreOi$0)....

Comment: Don't think so. VC++ generates the same.

Comment: @KarthikT: I am not sure how your linked code supports the "is a bug"-argument.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No that is not a bug. There are three parallel sets of operators considered. Members, non-member operators, and builtins.

The non-member ones are looked up by normal unqualified+ADL lookup, ignoring all class member functions. Hence the global operator is hidden by a lexical more closer one (and an intervening member function wouldn't have hidden other non-members).

Note that overload resolution takes place *after* name lookup<sup>1</sup>; in your case the name `operator++` was found, but no appropriate overload.

If Bar had been declared globally, and/or the other operator in namespace asdf, ADL (in the former case) or ordinary unqualified lookup (in the latter case) would have dragged the operator in.

---

<sup>1</sup>: `Overload resolution (...) takes place after name lookup has succeeded.` (C++ Standard)

Comment: I am not sure if this is enough detail. In case of a non-match, shouldn't the next enclosing namespace be looked up?

Comment: @phresnel: But how does the name `operator++` form a non-match for `operator++`? It is only the *name* that is relevant during name lookup.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau: I was provoking litb to add this detail (trying to think through the questioners perspective, if you want); as is, I don't think I can upvote already.

Comment: @phresnel feel free to improve the answer by editing it. hugs

Answer (score 8):

No, this is not a compiler bug.

There are two name-lookups that get performed for the expression `++bar`.

- The regular name lookup searches the enclosing scopes and namespaces until it finds the *first* occurence of `operator++`. This search works inside out, so the global namespace is searched last. When looking for operator functions, member-functions are treated separately (and don't stop this search).
- The argument-dependent lookup kicks in next and searches additional classes and namespaces, but only those that are related to the arguments of the function (`operator++` in this case).

In the example in the question, the normal lookup finds `asdf::operator++` and stops looking.
The argument-dependent lookup only adds the `asdf` namespace to the places to search, because that is the associated namespace for `enum Bar`. For that reason, the global `operator++` can not be found.

You can make the global `operator++` be found with a using declaration in namespace `asdf`.

Comment: the first bullet you describe does not consider class scopes. that is, even if in a class member function you use an operator expression, a namespace scope operator, even in a nonadl related namespace scope, can be found despite there being a member operator with the same name.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Is that a change between C++03 and C++11? Because I can't find such an exception in C++03 clause 3.4.1 [basic.lookup.unqual].

Comment: the rules are specified in 13.3.1.2 :-)

Comment: I'm porting code between compilers. Compiler A accepts the code in this  question (it apparently includes the global operator for overload resolution as well) - should that be considered a compiler bug?

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Yes, if compiler A accepts the code in this question, when invoked in its conforming mode, then compiler A has a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Overloading only applies to names defined **in the same scope**. Once the compiler finds a matching name it doesn't look in outer scopes, even if the name it found applies to something that can't be used. This has nothing to do with operators; if the code used a function name in the same way that it uses operator++ it would get the same error. For example:

```
void f(int);

struct C {
void f(const C&);
void g() {
    f(3); // error: f(const C&) can't be called with argument 3
};
```