# Is it bad style to overload operators on std containers in global scope?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, argument-dependent-lookup

I had this problem arise:

```
// A.h
#include <vector>
typedef std::vector<unsigned char> Buffer;
Buffer &operator+=(Buffer &a, Buffer const &b);
```

---

```
// B.h
namespace Bar
{
     struct Qux { };
     Qux &operator+=(Qux &a, Qux const &b);
}
```

---

```
// Foo.cpp
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"      // comment this out, error goes away

namespace Bar
{
    void foo()
    {
        Buffer a, b;
        a += b;       // error
    }
 }
```

The problem (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354186/operator-in-namespace-scope-hiding-another-in-global-scope)) is that `a += b;` fails to compile because `Bar::operator+=(Qux&, Qux const &)` hides `::operator+=`; and ADL does not find `::operator+` because ADL only searches `namespace std;` in this case.

This is icky because the problem only appears if `B.h` is included -- but `B.h` apparently has nothing to do with `Buffer` . Code shouldn't break depending on whether I include another header.

(Actually I discovered this only when changing compilers, the previous compiler I was using did name lookup incorrectly and accepted the code).

My question is: is the overload in `A.h` just a bad idea because of this issue?

I work around the issue for now by having `B.h` do `using ::operator+=;` inside `namespace Bar` but this seems pretty hacky, is there a better option?

Comment: What if you add `using ::operator+=;` to your code?

Comment: I think Kerrek means what happens if you add `using ::operator+=;` to `foo`?

Comment: you mean adding that to every function that uses it ? Seems even hackier than doing it once in `B.h` :)

Comment: If you are going to overload any operator for any of the types defined in `std` namespace, I would suggest doing that in `std` namespace. That would work very well with ADL.

Comment: @RSahu sadly it's UB to add to `std`  (see `[namespace.std]#1`)

Comment: You could change `Buffer` into a thin wrapper around `vector<unsigned char>` instead of a `typedef`. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/34a83feb3a92b4be (inheritance is just an example to show it works)

Comment: *Code shouldn't break depending on whether I include another header.* => that's why we are all eagerly waiting for [modules](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4047.pdf) :)

Comment: @MattMcNabb: in practice, it works quite well... but I still prefer a thin wrapper instead.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest, safest, most reusable approach I can think of is to have one of the `+=` arguments be of a type in the operator's namespace:

```
template <typename T>
struct ArgumentRef
{
    ArgumentRef(T& t) : t_(t) { }
    operator T&() { return t_; }
    operator const T&() const { return t_; }
    T& t_;
};

typedef std::vector<unsigned char> Buffer;
Buffer &operator+=(ArgumentRef<Buffer> a, Buffer const &b) { }
```

That said, inheritance - while controversial in C++ circles due to the non-virtual destructor in `vector` - is often fine IMHO, especially if you aren't exposing `Buffer` in an API for wider use, and not using dynamically allocated instances in code also designed to own and handle the base class.

Answer (score 2):

Though I'm not sure whether operator overloading in this case is of bad style or not,
(it might be kind of arguable issue, as you know),
it seems an issue of 'function scope', rather than an issue of 'operator'.
Even if you change 'operator+=()' to 'Add()',
you may get the same result.

It would be irrelevant to the issue whether operator overloading in this case is of bad style or not.

Comment: That's quite true; so I could also work around this by calling my function "my_buffer_append" which is less likely to have a clash than `operator+=`.